# Method reCalling

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

im kinda new to iOS.
I know that a `void method` i.e

```
-(void) pressed {

}
```

can be called this way:

```
[self pressed];
```

and `viewDidAppear`
can be called something like this:

```
[self viewDidAppear:YES];
```

I was wandering on how to do it in this method below, or how to re-Call it:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{

    return [images count];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may me data source method... It is called from a controller.

```
//And it may be called in the controller as below where delegate is object of some class
    iCarousel *iCarouselObj;
    if(delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(numberOfItemsInCarousel:)])
        int items = [delegate numberOfItemsInCarousel:iCarouselObj];

//The below code is just to tell you how to call a method with arguments
iCarousel *iCarouselObj;
int items = [self numberOfItemsInCarousel:iCarouselObj];
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`, it's part of the `UIViewController` lifecycle and it will be called automatically. As for the other one:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return [images count];
}
```

I never used `iCarousel`, but it seems to be a method from the Data source, and, as such, shouldn't be called directly as well.